# change placeholder text for each option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so how can I achieve that?I've already tried this code down below but it doesn't work

```
var placeholderText = {
        "Mobile": "0932-XXX-XXXX or 0932xxxxxxx",
        "Landline": "123-4567",
        "FAX": "+(country code)(area code)(fax number)",
        "Email": "sample@example.com",
};

$("#ModalContactType").on("click", function () {
  if (this.value != 0) {
    $("#ModalDetail").val(placeholderText[$("#ModalContactType option:selected").text()]);
  } 
  else {
    $("#ModalDetail").val("");
  }

});
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<select id="ModalContactType">
    <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Mobile</option>
    <option value="2">Landline</option>
    <option value="3">FAX</option>
    <option value="4">Email</option>
</select>
```

And here

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">Detail</div>
    <input type="text" id="ModalDetail" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: what is your required result? it's not obvious what you want to achieve - because the code you posted does update the input

Comment: perhaps you want to change the `placeholder` attribute instead? i.e. `$("#ModalDetail").attr('placeholder', "");`

Comment: *it doesn't work* provides no clue at all to the problem you are experiencing. Clearly it doesn't work, why else would you resort to asking a question in the last place you'd want to go, stack overflow!! debugging 101 - check the browser developer tools console for errors - if your code is running before the HTML is loaded, you could get *errors*

Comment: you tag `javascript` and use `jquery` please see my answer to do it in `javascript` or in  `Jquery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see code bellow in **Jquery**:
**use `onchange()` and add jquery script**

```js
var placeholderText = {
        "Mobile": "0932-XXX-XXXX or 0932xxxxxxx",
        "Landline": "123-4567",
        "FAX": "+(country code)(area code)(fax number)",
        "Email": "sample@example.com",
    };
 function  setPlaceholder(){
 
         if (this.value != 0) {
            $("#ModalDetail").val(placeholderText[$("#ModalContactType option:selected").text()]);
        } 
        else {
            $("#ModalDetail").val("");
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ModalContactType" onchange="setPlaceholder()">
      <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
       <option value="1">Mobile</option>
      <option value="2">Landline</option>
     <option value="3">FAX</option>
     <option value="4">Email</option>
</select>

<div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">Detail</div>
     <input type="text" id="ModalDetail" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

**OR using javascript:**

```js
    var placeholderText = {
            "Mobile": "0932-XXX-XXXX or 0932xxxxxxx",
            "Landline": "123-4567",
            "FAX": "+(country code)(area code)(fax number)",
            "Email": "sample@example.com",
        };
     function  setPlaceholder(slc){
     
             if (this.value != 0) {
                document.getElementById("ModalDetail").value=placeholderText[slc.options[slc.selectedIndex].text];
            } 
            else {
                 document.getElementById("ModalDetail").value="";
            }
        }
```

```html
    <select id="ModalContactType" onchange="setPlaceholder(this)">
          <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
           <option value="1">Mobile</option>
          <option value="2">Landline</option>
         <option value="3">FAX</option>
         <option value="4">Email</option>
    </select>

    <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-addon">Detail</div>
         <input type="text" id="ModalDetail" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:**

to set `placeholder` and not `text`:

```
document.getElementById("ModalDetail").placeholder="...";
```

```js
        var placeholderText = {
                "Mobile": "0932-XXX-XXXX or 0932xxxxxxx",
                "Landline": "123-4567",
                "FAX": "+(country code)(area code)(fax number)",
                "Email": "sample@example.com",
            };
         function  setPlaceholder(slc){
         
                 if (this.value != 0) {
                    document.getElementById("ModalDetail").placeholder=placeholderText[slc.options[slc.selectedIndex].text];
                } 
                else {
                     document.getElementById("ModalDetail").placeholder="";
                }
            }
```

```html
        <select id="ModalContactType" onchange="setPlaceholder(this)">
              <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
               <option value="1">Mobile</option>
              <option value="2">Landline</option>
             <option value="3">FAX</option>
             <option value="4">Email</option>
        </select>

        <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-addon">Detail</div>
             <input type="text" id="ModalDetail" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help\

Comment: yes its right! but how can i let the text like stay in the background like when i input in the text box the placeholder text will disappear? to make it more user friendly

Comment: should i replace the .value " document.getElementById("ModalDetail").value=""; " to placeholder? is that what you meant?

Comment: is it helps for you?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing same code, its working fine. the problem is script moved to end of the body tag

```js
var placeholderText = {
        "Mobile": "0932-XXX-XXXX or 0932xxxxxxx",
        "Landline": "123-4567",
        "FAX": "+(country code)(area code)(fax number)",
        "Email": "sample@example.com",
    };

    $("#ModalContactType").on("click", function () {
        if (this.value != 0) {
            $("#ModalDetail").val(placeholderText[$("#ModalContactType option:selected").text()]);
        } 
        else {
            $("#ModalDetail").val("");
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ModalContactType">
  <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Mobile</option>
  <option value="2">Landline</option>
  <option value="3">FAX</option>
  <option value="4">Email</option>
</select>
                            
                            
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Detail</div>
  <input type="text" id="ModalDetail" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the backtick (`) at the end of your javascript it should work fine. Also ensure that you are defining your html tags before importing the script.

Comment: Can any one tell me why it got a -1 ?